# Excel VBA - N number of Random records per unique group

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on developing a system health check tool to validate that 4 different systems are in sync. To do that, I need to create a sample dataset of random N number of records for every unique key/combination from a main data set everyday. All 4 systems will be checked for records from this sample dataset and any differences will be highlighted using conditional formatting.

I am having trouble figuring out how to extract the sample dataset from the main dataset with the criteria mentioned above.

For Example, I have a report that has 700 rows. Each unique combination (concatenation to create a key) of the 6 fields [Client-Contractor-Distribution Center-Service Level-Alert Value-Status] has 100 records. This part will be dynamic. There could be any number of unique combinations and any number of records per combination. Image below for reference. Only the groups are shown here as I cannot paste 700 records in the question. There are 7 unique groups with 100 records each.

There are some questions in the comments for which I am giving the clarifications below:
-Combination/Group = Basically a key created with concatenation of the focus columns to recognize/define a category the records may belong to. As example concating First Name & Last Name to create a unique identity of a person.

- All records will be on a single sheet. It is a report downloaded from a system.
- Sequence of the records of each grouping: All records of a particular group will not be bunched together. All records are dumped from the system on the report. We are creating the group/key by concating the focus columns.

[image]

Let's say I want 5 random records for each of the 7 GroupKeys. Essentially, I need a way to get 35 records that are randomly selected, 5 per unique combination.
A sample of the desired output is shown below.
[image]

I have tried using RAND() and RANDBETWEEN() formulas. I do get random records. But the problem is that I cannot ensure that I get 5 records per combination and sometimes duplicate records are returned as well. I am open to any method (VBA/Formulas) to achieve this.

This is a very complex problem for someone like me who is only a novice/beginner at VBA at most.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [N number of Random Records per Unique Combination (Key)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69268902/n-number-of-random-records-per-unique-combination-key)

Comment: What have you tried? Only changing your question title won't get you answers.. Edit your question with your code attempt, explain what's wrong and we will be happy to help

Comment: Are what you name "groups", grouped on the sheet? Or all the "group" elements are spread on all these 700 rows? If spread, you can simple group them using a dictionary and the concatenation of the specific columns content as keys and as items an array of each item row. Finally you can determine how many elements contains each group, create an array of random numbers and match it with the rows array, extracting 5 such rows based on the (random) rank.

Comment: Then, could not show us 700 rows, but you should show, at least for two categories/groups, how are they placed in the sheet to be processed. If each group has only consecutive rows, it will be a little easy, skipping the part of grouping. It should also be better if your picture shows also the columns headers. Should we consider that they are in the range "A:G"?

Comment: Is it a mistake in the second group example (Client 1 to 5, Contractor 1 to 5 and so on)? If not, what to be the unique key or selection them?

Comment: When place a question, you should check from time to time if clarification questions have been asked... I made some assumptions and placed answer. Please, check it and send some feedback.

Comment: Apologies @FaneDuru, I was in a workshop today so did not have access to the laptop. I have edited the question to hopefully clarify your doubts. The Client1-5 & Contractor 1-5 was a mistake. Have replaced with the correct image.

Comment: @RaymondWu, the challenge here is so complex for a beginner at VBA like me that I don't even know where to start. I tried the formula approach but I don't think what I require is achievable with formulas. And as FaneDuru mentioned. I have no training in any programming language. I can write basic VBA or patch in a code with required changes from already solved topics that are similar to my requirement. But I could not find anything close to what I am looking for in this topic.

Comment: Why didn't you test the code I  posted? If tested, didn't it do what you need? i asked for some feedback... It assumes what I presumed in a previous comment and you still did not clarify the issue: the data to be processed is in the columns "A:G".

Comment: @AchalDesai I do understand your position but SO is not a place where you throw your entire problem statement and expect people to solve it for you with a full code. Even if you are a beginner, you have to start somewhere, try something out first then ask us to help you with your code. FaneDuru is kind enough to provide you a complete solution although you have not show any effort in it so please work with him and accept his answer to acknowledge his effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, test the next code. It needs a reference to 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime':

```
Sub RandomRecPerGroup()
   Dim sh As Worksheet, shRet As Worksheet, lastR As Long, dict As New Scripting.Dictionary
   Dim arr, arrIt, i As Long, j As Long, f As Long, k As Long, count As Long, arrFin
   
   Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here the sheet you need
   Set shRet = sh.Next  'use here the sheet you need (for testing reason, the next against the active one)
   shRet.Range("G1").EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "@"   'format the column to keep 'Reference number' as text
   lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last row
   arr = sh.Range("A2:G" & lastR).Value ' place the range in an array for faster iteration
   ReDim arrFin(1 To 5, 1 To 7): k = 1  'reDim the array to keep each group
   For i = 1 To UBound(arr)             'iterate between the array elements:
        'create a dictionary key if not already existing, with the number of the row as item:
        If Not dict.Exists(arr(i, 1) & arr(i, 2) & arr(i, 3) & arr(i, 4) & arr(i, 5) & arr(i, 6)) Then
            dict.Add arr(i, 1) & arr(i, 2) & arr(i, 3) & arr(i, 4) & arr(i, 5) & arr(i, 6), i
        Else 'adding the number of row, separated by "|"
            dict(arr(i, 1) & arr(i, 2) & arr(i, 3) & arr(i, 4) & arr(i, 5) & arr(i, 6)) = _
                  dict(arr(i, 1) & arr(i, 2) & arr(i, 3) & arr(i, 4) & arr(i, 5) & arr(i, 6)) & "|" & i
        End If
   Next i
   Dim rndNo As Long              'a variable to receive the random number
   For i = 0 To dict.count - 1    'iterate between the dictionary elements:
        arrIt = Split(dict.items(i), "|"): ' split the item by "|" to obtain the same group existing rows
        For k = 1 To 5            'iterate to extract the 5 necessary sample rows of each group
                Randomize         'initialize the random numbers generation
                If UBound(arrIt) = -1 Then Exit For     'for the case of less than 5 rows per group
                rndNo = CLng(UBound(arrIt) * Rnd())     'give a value to the variable keeping the random numbers
                For f = 1 To 7                          'iterating to place in the array all 7 columns value
                    arrFin(k, f) = arr(arrIt(rndNo), f)
                Next f
                arrIt = Filter(arrIt, arrIt(rndNo), False) 'eliminate the element just placed in an array, to avoid doubling
        Next k
        lastR = shRet.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row + 1 'last empty row of the sheet where the result is returned
        shRet.Range("A" & lastR).Resize(5, 7).Value = arrFin       'drop the array content
   Next i
   MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub
```

The code may work without the mentioned reference (using labe binding), but I think it should be good to benefit of intellisense suggestions. If it looks complicated to create it, please (**firstly**) run the next code which will add it automatically:

```
Sub addScrRunTimeRef()
  'Add a reference to 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime':
  'In case of error ('Programmatic access to Visual Basic Project not trusted'):
  'Options->Trust Center->Trust Center Settings->Macro Settings->Developer Macro Settings->
  '         check "Trust access to the VBA project object model"
  On Error Resume Next
  Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.References.AddFromFile "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\scrrun.dll"
  If err.Number = 32813 Then
        err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0
        MsgBox "The reference already exists...": Exit Sub
  Else
        On Error GoTo 0
        MsgBox """Microsoft Scripting Runtime"" reference added successfully..."
  End If
End Sub
```

Saving the workbook will keep the reference. So, no need to run the code again...

Comment: This worked!!! However, I have a few questions. From reading through the code and understanding as much as I could, It looks like this code can only work if the dataset gas 7 unique groups. Is that correct?  Because in actual application, there can be anywhere between 500 and 200 unique groups and thousands of records in each group.

Comment: @Achal Desai Not really... It works for as many groups exist on the sheet. The 7 in the code means the columns to be concatenated when build the five random chosen rows on each group. It processes all unique concatenations between the first six columns and make an array of the rows of all occurrences per each group. Then, it randomly return five of them. The code is also prepared for the case when the maximum of occurrences is less then five...

Comment: @Achal Desai But, even not experienced, I would like to remember that we here, when somebody answer our question, tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the code works...

Answer (score 0):

So basically you have 700 possibilities, and you want to get 5 random values out of them, while you are sure that you don't have duplicates?

There are, basically, two ways to do this:

- You make a resulting collection of random values, you use the random generator to generate numbers from 1 to 700, but before adding them to your collection, you verify if they are already present in your collection. Something like (pseudo-code):

  ```
    Dim col_Result as Collection
    Dim finished as Boolean = False;
    Dim r as integer;

    while (not finished){
         r = ConvertToInt(Random(700)) + 1;
         if not(col_Result.Contains(r))
         then col_Result.Add(r);
         finished = (col_Result.Count == 5);
    }
  ```
- You make a collection of all numbers from 1 to 700, and 5 times you retrieve a random value out of it, while subtracting that value from the collection. Something like (pseudo-code again):

  ```
    Dim col_Values as Collection = (1, 2, ..., 700);
    Dim col_Result as Collection;

    Dim r as integer;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        r = ConvertToInt(Random(700));
        col_Result.Add(r);
        col_Values.Subtract(r);
    }
  ```

When using this last approach, it is vital that subtracting a value from the collection shifts the other values: `(1,2,3,4,5).Subtract(2)` yields `(1,3,4,5)`.

Comment: This should be VBA code, I think. :) And it looks you missed the point related to existing 'groups'...

Comment: @FaneDuru: my answer is just a hint to the right direction, it's not meant to be real code (hence my "pseudo-code" remark :-) ). Don't forget that the author asked the question, asked the question again, but didn't show any effort to implement something (hence my choice of providing pseudo-code, not real code).

Comment: I can understand that, but I am afraid that OP do  not know too much about any programming language. Otherwise, he should provide his own attempt, as I suggested when he firstly posted something similar... Usually, I do not answer a question not showing a minimum effort of doing the job by OP himself. Now, seeing your answer and the question looking challenging (on my taste), I dared an answer... :)